# Changing multiple images on the same page

Tags: javascript

I am using this script to loop through images on mouseover. How do I make this work for multiple pictures on the same page?

```
<script>
var myImages = [1, 2, 3]
var img_index = 0;
var timer;
var imgId = "myImg";

// Start animation
function animate() {
    me = document.getElementById(imgId);

    me.src = "Pictures/" + "test"  + myImages[img_index] + ".png"

    img_index++;

    if (img_index == myImages.length){
        img_index = 0;
    }
     timer = setTimeout(animate, 500);

}

function stopAnimation() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
   me.src="Pictures/test1.png"
}
</script>

<img class= "format" id="myImg" onmouseover="imgId = this.id; timer = setTimeout(animate, 1000);" onmouseout="stopAnimation();" src="Pictures/test1.png" />
```

Comment: Refactor it so it takes some arguments and is generic enough to do it. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have a case-specific function that must be adapted in order to work with any given element. In order to do this you should replace constants and global variables with local variables, specifically function arguments. Ideally, you need a function that can take an HTML node, an array, and a delay time. Additionally, for this specific problem you can use recursion in order to get rid of the `var img_index`.

I would do this:

```
var myImages = [1, 2, 3];
var timeouts={};

// Start Animation of HTML object obj with images in array arr and a delay time.
function startAnimation(obj,arr,time){
   timeouts[obj.id] = setTimeout(function(){
      animate(this,arr,time,0);
   },time);
}
// Animate, index used to keep track of image number
function animate(obj,arr,time,index){
   obj.src = "Pictures/" + "test"  + arr[index] + ".png";
   timeouts[obj.id] = setTimeout(function(){
      animate(this,arr,time,(index==arr.length)?0:index++);
   },time);
}
// End the animation of HTML object obj
function stopAnimation(obj){
   clearTimeout(timeouts[obj.id]);
}
```

Since you want to apply your code to several animations, you must consider a way to use more than one array (one per animation). This is what the argument `arr` is for. Additionally, you must consider different HTML elements (images), which is what the argument `obj` is for. There is no need to use `document.getElementById(...)` if you pass the function a reference to an object rather than an id. In other words, the animation function is working with a reference to the image element rather than it's id. Also, you might want to vary the time delay from animation to animation, which is what the `time` argument is for.

The `animate(...)` function calls itself (recursion) while adding one to the `index` argument. This achieves the same as your `img_index` variable, but without an additional variable.

And HTML:

```
<img class="format" id="myImg" onmouseover="startAnimation(this,myImages,500)" onmouseout="stopAnimation(this);" src="Pictures/test1.png" />
```

In this case, the variable `this` points to the image element. In general, when handling events it points to the element that fired the event.

Or, alternatively you could assign the event handlers with JavaScript instead of in-line:

```
document.getElementById("myImg").onmouseover = function(){
   startAnimation(this,myImages,500)
}
document.getElementById("myImg").onmouseout = function(){
   stopAnimation(this)
}
```

Comment: I am new to javascript. Can you explain if I need to use your code with parts of my code and how it works?

Comment: @PornSINsation: I edited the post. Hopefully it makes more sense now. The code should work as-is, without adding any parts of yours.